# How to do scanf for single char in C

Tags: c, char, scanf

In C:
I'm trying to get char from the user with `scanf` and when I run it the program don't wait for the user to type anything...

This is the code:

```
char ch;
printf("Enter one char");
scanf("%c", &ch);
printf("%c\n",ch);
```

Why is not working?

Comment: Just to clarify here, if the C program contains *only* the code above, it will work as expected. Potential problems like the one OP mentions only arise when it is used together with other I/O code, for reasons mentioned in P.P's answer.

Answer (score 304):

The `%c` conversion specifier won't automatically skip any leading whitespace, so if there's a stray newline in the input stream (from a previous entry, for example) the `scanf` call will consume it immediately.

One way around the problem is to put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

The blank in the format string tells `scanf` to skip leading whitespace, and the first non-whitespace character will be read with the `%c` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 39):

First of all, avoid `scanf()`. Using it is not worth the pain.

See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Using a whitespace character in `scanf()` would ignore any number of whitespace characters left in the input stream, what if you need to read more inputs? Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char ch1, ch2;

   scanf("%c", &ch1);  /* Leaves the newline in the input */
   scanf(" %c", &ch2); /* The leading whitespace ensures it's the
                          previous newline is ignored */
   printf("ch1: %c, ch2: %c\n", ch1, ch2);

   /* All good so far */

   char ch3;
   scanf("%c", &ch3); /* Doesn't read input due to the same problem */
   printf("ch3: %c\n", ch3);

   return 0;
}
```

While the 3rd scanf() can be fixed in the same way using a leading whitespace, it's not always going to that simple as above.
Another major problem is, `scanf()` will not discard any input in the input stream if it doesn't match the format. For example, if you input `abc` for an `int` such as: `scanf("%d", &int_var);` then `abc` will have to read and discarded. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    while(1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) { /* Input "abc" */
            printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Int read: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Another common problem is mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()`. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int age;
    char name[256];
    printf("Input your age:");
    scanf("%d", &age); /* Input 10 */
    printf("Input your full name [firstname lastname]");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin); /* Doesn't read! */
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `fgets()` doesn't wait for input because the newline left by the previous scanf() call is read and fgets() terminates input reading when it encounters a newline.

There are many other similar problems associated with `scanf()`. That's why it's generally recommended to avoid it.

So, what's the alternative? Use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) function instead in the following fashion to read a single character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[256];
    char ch;

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Input error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ch = line[0];
    printf("Character read: %c\n", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

One detail to be aware of when using `fgets()` will read in the newline character if there's enough room in the inut buffer. If it's not desirable then you can remove it:

```
char line[256];

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("Input error.\n");
    exit(1);
}

line[strcpsn(line, "\n")] = 0; /* removes the trailing newline, if present */
```

Answer (score 12):

This works for me try it out

```
int main(){
char c;
scanf(" %c",&c);
printf("%c",c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now that's wild!  Would you explain why the space in front of `%c` makes a difference?

Comment: Solved: [check](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502486/why-is-this-statement-printed-twice-in-while-loop/29502522#29502522) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869502/in-c-programming-how-to-print-1-character/23869739#23869739)

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any more information than the accepted answer from 2012.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a similiar thing that I would like to share,

while you're working on Visual Studio you could get an error like:

> 'scanf': function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using `scanf_s` instead. To disable deprecation, use `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

To prevent this, you should write it in the following format

A single character may be read as follows:

```
char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

When multiple characters for non-null terminated strings are read, integers are used as the width specification and the buffer size.

```
char c[4];
scanf_s("%4c", &c, _countof(c));
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for me.
Unhandled exception at 0x799AF2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Deitel0805.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {
 char c;
 printf("%s", "Please enter a character:");
 scanf_s("%с", &c, 1);
 
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

neither fgets nor getchar works to solve the problem.
the only workaround is keeping a space before %c while using scanf
scanf(" %c",ch);  // will only work

In the follwing fgets also not work..

```
char line[256];
char ch;
int i;

printf("Enter a num : ");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("Enter a char : ");

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("Input error.\n");
    exit(1);
}

ch = line[0];
printf("Character read: %c\n", ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

The only code that worked for me is:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

I was having the same problem, and only with single characters. After an hour of random testing I can not report an issue yet. One would think that C would have by now a bullet-proof function to retrieve single characters from the keyboard, and not an array of possible hackarounds... Just saying...

Comment: How exactly is this attempting to add value over older, existing answers?

Comment: Actually after reading the whole thread I would have to conclude there is no definitive answer here... just workarounds

Answer (score 1):

try using getchar(); instead

syntax:

```
void main() {
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before the scanf put `fflush(stdin);` to clear buffer.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behaviour* per C standard.

Comment: This is not correct, `fflush(stdin)` is UB, mentioned in lots of question at SO.

Comment: It works with Microsoft compiler but that's about it

Answer (score -2):

Use string instead of `char`
like

```
char c[10];
scanf ("%s", c);
```

I belive it works nice.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because the OP wanted to `scanf` a _single character_, not a series of them.

Answer (score -3):

Provides a space before %c conversion specifier so that compiler will ignore white spaces. The program may be written as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    printf("Enter one char");
    scanf(" %c", &ch); /*Space is given before %c*/
    printf("%c\n",ch);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the same suggestion John Bode gave two years ago.

Answer (score -4):

You have to use a valid variable. `ch` is not a valid variable for this program. Use `char Aaa`;

```
char aaa;
scanf("%c",&Aaa);
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: "ch is not a valid variable for this program" Except it is? It's the first line of code in the given example.

Comment: This answer is very useful. I did not know that C compiler is not case-sensitive. For example: `THIS_ANSWER_IS_BAD` can be detected by C compiler as `this_answer_is_BAD`. Oh, it should be `mychar`, not `ch`, tested it and it works.