# Structures in C Language

Tags: c, structure

what is mistake ? i cant find any mistake in my code but it does not take input properly and it also displays some garbage values.
Thanks:

```
int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        int price;
        int pages;
    };
    struct book b[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("enter name price pages\n");
        scanf("%c", &b[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &b[i].price);
        scanf("%d", &b[i].pages);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%c %d %d\n", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure you didn't mean to use `char*` instead of `char`, or do you only require one character?

Comment: You are aware, presumably, that `book` at present can only have a single letter name.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun: it probaby should be `char name[32];` or something similar — at least for a person asking this level of C question. Dynamic memory allocation comes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've been informed to specifically answer the question (sorry, Im new here), the problem lies in the %c picking up whitespace and/or newline characters.  The easiest way to prevent this is put a " " in front of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name; 
        int price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("enter name price pages\n");
        scanf(" %c %d %d",&b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);  //here
        //%c was grabbing whitespace and/or newline causing the problem.
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("Name:  %c Price:  %d Pages:  %d\n",b[i].name,b[i].price,b[i].pages);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

enter name price pages

a 1 2

enter name price pages

b 3 4

enter name price pages

c 5 6

enter name price pages

d 7 8

enter name price pages

e 9 10

Name:  a Price:  1 Pages:  2

Name:  b Price:  3 Pages:  4

Name:  c Price:  5 Pages:  6

Name:  d Price:  7 Pages:  8

Name:  e Price:  9 Pages:  10

Comment: This is not the problem, he wants a single character to identify the book.

Comment: Removed presumed change to char array.

Answer (score 3):

Most books have a name that is longer than a single letter.

You need to adjust the structure accordingly:

```
enum { MAX_BOOKNAMELEN = 32 }; // Probably too short

struct book
{
    char name[MAX_BOOKNAMELEN];
    int price;
    int pages;
};
```

You also need to adjust the input:

```
    if (scanf("%31[^\n]", b[i].name) != 1)
        ...report error; do not use this book entry...
```

The '31' is magicked out of thin air; it is one less than `MAX_BOOKNAMELEN`. Note that book titles frequently contain spaces; thus `%s` which skips leading spaces and stops at the first space after one or more non-space characters is not appropriate for reading titles. One way to create the format string is via `sprintf()` — this will adapt if `MAX_BOOKNAMELEN` changes size:

```
char name_fmt[16];
snprintf(name_fmt, sizeof(name_fmt), "%%%d[^\n]", MAX_BOOKNAMELEN-1);

if (scanf(name_fmt, b[i].name) != 1)
    ...error...
```

A more thorough revision would probably use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or other tools instead of calling `scanf()` directly.

Comment: i am only ussing single charcter for word but still thers problem

Comment: If you really mean to support just 256 different possible book titles, then I suppose [Mohamed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003575/mohamed) has given you the necessary [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20428585/15168). However, one-letter book titles will pall after a while; then you can come back to the techniques in this answer.

Comment: Thanks, Eric Postpischil.

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
scanf("%c",&b[i].name);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c",&b[i].name);
```

See [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/in-c-how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char)

Comment: @Bathsheba Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/in-c-how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the last scanf("%d"), reads the number and let a '\n' at the buffer, so next time you call scanf("%c"), it will read the '\n' in the buffer, and not the new character.

One possible solution to use scanf, is to tell scanf to read everything in the line, and discard it:

```
    scanf("%c%*[^\n]\n", &b[i].name);
    scanf("%d%*[^\n]\n", &b[i].price);
    scanf("%d%*[^\n]\n", &b[i].pages);
```

This way, scanf will block until you press enter, and will read the '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

```
scanf(" %c %d %d",&b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);
while(getchar()!='\n');
```