# in C programming, how to print 1 character

Tags: c

I've made the following but it skips the part where I have to input the character and I don't understand what my mistake is. Any help ?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main()
{
  int num;
  float f;
  char c;

  printf("Input an integer: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &num);

  printf("Input an floating point number: ");
  scanf_s("%f", &f);

  printf("Input a character: ");
  scanf_s("%c", &c);

  printf("\nThe number is: %d\n",num);
  printf("\nThe floating point number is: %f\n", f);
  printf("\nThe character is: %c\n", c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So are you asking about _printing_ a character as you say in the title, or about _reading_ a character as you say in the text?

Comment: The question / title might be a bit vague, but the problem is not. It's the standard issue with `scanf()` and newlines. I am certain there are hundreds of duplicates, but I can't find any ATM...

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &c);` --> `scanf_s(" %c", &c, 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 scanf_s("%d", &d);
```

This reads characters as long as they fit the `"%d"` format. The first character not fitting that format is the newline you entered. This remains in the input stream.

```
 scanf_s("%f", &f);
```

This **skips leading whitespaces** (i.e., your newline), then reads characters as long as they fit the `"%f"` format. The first character not fitting that format is the newline you entered. This remains in the input stream.

```
 scanf_s("%c", &c);
```

This reads one character from the input **without skipping potential leading whitespace**, i.e., your newline.

It also is undefined behaviour: One thing that `scanf_s()` does differently than standard `scanf()` is that it demands a "buffer size" numerical parameter for `%c` and `%s`, to avoid buffer overflow. Not *giving* that parameter makes `scanf_s()` pull an integer from the stack where you didn't put one, resulting in undefined behaviour. If that next memory address *happens* to be zero, you'll be scratching your head a lot I would bet...

Comment: Nice explanation. I am going to link this answer in my site(I linked below).

Comment: See Survaf93 and G.Samaras, who give advice on how to skip leading whitespace before invoking `%c`.

Comment: @user3676215: No problem. This (newlines remaining in input stream) is actually one of the most common beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not wrong your `scanf_s("%c", &c);` reads the '\n' character from the previous input.

What you can do is add 1 space before %c so:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &c);
```

that will fix your issue. Remember you need to do that if reading a character after some previous input.
Tested and works.

Comment: What does the space mean in that context?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot: "Skip leading whitespace". Exactly what `%c` does not do by default, but `%d` and `%f` do. (As a whitespace is not valid in a number, but a valid character.)

Comment: @DevSolar does this can be applied to %s too?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot: One or more whitespaces in the format specification match any number of whitespaces in the input. What kind of conversion specifier follows is irrelevant.

Comment: Correct my mistake, %s reads until it reaches '\s' or '\n'.

Comment: While we're at it, `scanf_s()` actually *does* need a size parameter when used with `"%c"` (see answer by TheCrafter, who didn't address the whitespace issue though). So please either add the parameter, or use standard `scanf()`. As it stands now, your answer is not correct code, and actually invokes UB. (So much for "security" extensions.)

Answer (score -1):

Specify the size. Use this line:

```
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

It should work!

Comment: Good catch on the additional parameter, but doesn't address the real problem.