# Error in detecting uppercase letters

Tags: c

Yesterday we had an exam in a C language course and question was something like that:

1. Write a function called **toLowercase** which takes a character as a parameter and returns uppercase letters to lowercase. If the character is not upper case, the function should return it unchanged.
2. write a program that takes arbitrarily many characters from user (until s/he enter "!") and then outputs first and last entered uppercase letters in lowercase form.

   a. If the user enters only one uppercase letter, program should output that uppercase letter twice in lowercase form.

   b. We can assume that user always enters at least one uppercase letter.

### Example Inputs and Desired Outputs

`lskdjfSFFKAFfkafafkKFAFkaKfgRORELKkjfks!` ====> `sk`
`Mdsfisjf98948*3jkfHf9059,353953,^+%^+%!` ====> `mh`
`sjfhsfR'^^''jfi2jpfj99ejfsdfs` ====> `rr`

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char toLower(char n){
    char m=' ';
    if(n>='A'&&n<='Z'){
        m=n-'A'+'a';
        return m;
    }
    else
        return n;
}

int main(){
    int i=0;
    char ch,chmod,chFirst=' ',chLast=' ';
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    while(ch!='!'){
        chmod=toLower(ch);
        if(chmod!=ch){
            chLast=chmod;
            i++;
        }
        if(i==1)
            chFirst=chmod;

        scanf("%c",&ch);
    }
    if(i==1)
        chFirst=chLast;

    printf("%c%c",chFirst,chLast);



    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code with three different compilers and it outputs wrong results. There are some strange things. It results the first letter wrong but the second letter correct. If the input contains only one uppercase letter, the output is correct again. Lastly, I checked this code over and over again.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Please change your title to something meaningful "What's wrong with my code" won't help any other user that has the same problem, because it doesn't describe the problem.

Comment: No doubt that the subject needs a change but this question does not deserve negative and close votes. It is perfectly written, OP has tried to solve the problem, given his sample code etc. +1 for counteracting the negative votes given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic logic is here:

```
while(ch!='!'){
    chmod=toLower(ch);
    if(chmod!=ch){
        chLast=chmod;
        i++;
    }
    if(i==1)
        chFirst=chmod;

    scanf("%c",&ch);
}
```

Consider the case if the first letter is uppercase. Then, `chLast` will be changed, `i` incremented, then `chFirst` will be changed.

Now if the second letter is not uppercase, `i` will not be incremented and will still be `1`. So `chFirst` will be changed again, which is not what you want.

A better logic would be as follows:

```
while(ch!='!'){
    chmod=toLower(ch);
    if(chmod!=ch){
        chLast=chmod;
        if(i==0) {
            chFirst=chmod;
            i=1;
        }
    }
    scanf("%c",&ch);
}
```

In this improved logic, you are effectively using `i` as a boolean variable, with `0` indicating that `chFirst` is unset, and `1` indicating that `chFirst` is set. Note that your final check of `if(i==1) chFirst=chLast;` is not necessary.

Comment: It would be even more logical to check if `chFirst == '  '` (initial value)

Answer (score 1):

Set chFirst only if it's stil == ' ' and do it in the first if. This way you can get rid of variable i...

Comment: This is an improvement to the code but not solving the case. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

As @ace pointed out, there is a slight problem in your logic. The solution would be to bring this code:

```
  if(i==1)
        chFirst=chmod;
```

inside the previous `if` statement, like this:

```
if(chmod!=ch){
        chLast=chmod;
        i++;
          if(i==1)
        chFirst=chmod;
    }
```

[Correct output](http://ideone.com/QZxcu1)

Comment: No, it's not the case

Comment: Test the second case and you'll know your answer is wrong.

Comment: @ace: Thanks for pointing it out, didn't really check the second case

Comment: I don't understand what is difference between `scanf("%c",&ch)` and `scanf(" %c",&ch)` ?

Comment: @Ahmetİnal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c