# Converting temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I wrote a program that converts temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit. When I enter `c`, the code works as expected, but when I enter `f`, it gives me a random number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    float f,c;

    printf("x=Ende c=Umrechnung c->f f=Umrechnung f->c:");
    if(scanf("c",&c)==c){
        printf("Grad Celisius =");
        scanf("%f",&c);
        f=(c*1.8)+32;
        printf("%.2f Grad Celisius sind %.2f Grad Fahreiheit\n",c,f);
    }
    else if(scanf("f",&f)==f){
        printf("Grad fahrenheit =");
        scanf("%f",&f);
        c=(f-32)/1.8;
        printf("%.2f Grad Fahrenheit sind %.2f Grad Fahrenheit",f,c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: “it is wrong” is not an error description. What did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: when i execute  the program and type f to convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius it gave me a random numbers

Comment: if(scanf("c",&c)==c) why did you write this?

Comment: to make a condition (if i enter "c" the syntax below will execute )

Comment: well buddy unfortunately scanf does'nt work that way...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) command properly. I modified your code a little bit and this works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    float f,c;
    char ch;

    printf("x=Ende c=Umrechnung c->f f=Umrechnung f->c:");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if(ch=='c'){
        printf("Grad Celsius =");
        scanf("%f",&c);
        f=(c*1.8)+32;
        printf("%.2f Grad Celsius sind %.2f Grad Fahrenheit\n",c,f);
    }
    else if(ch=='f'){
        printf("Grad Fahrenheit =");
        scanf("%f",&f);
        c=(f-32)/1.8;
        printf("%.2f Grad Fahrenheit sind %.2f Grad Celsius",f,c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, you have read a character (`ch`) only once and compare it afterwards to the options that your program provides. Please note the space character in `" %c"` in the `scanf()` line. It might be needed so that the code works properly, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542055/2675154).

I guess that you also want to put a loop around your code, so that it makes sense to ask the user to enter an `x` in order to end the program. Currently the program terminates if you don't enter `c` or `f`. The program also terminates after one calculation has been done.

By the way, I also changed one `Celsius` to `Fahrenheit` in your last `printf()`. I think you confused the words there. I also changed `Celisius` to `Celsius`.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/294055) if you feel it was useful to you :)