# C program doesn't complete all steps

Tags: c, struct

my code here doesn't scan the character in scanf("%c", &c);, after printf("Enter the type of process); it directly terminate the program. could you please help me  I am a beginner at C.
[what happens in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGJWS.png)

Comment: Try adding a `default` to your switch, which prints the un-handled value of `c` you actually received. And, please paste you (minimal) code example here directly, instead of linking a screencap.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c) might help you!!!

Comment: It is better to put your code in the question that linking a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `default:` label to your `switch` statement that prints a message when a character other than `+-*/` is entered. Most likely the `scanf` operation isn't reading what you think it's reading.

(My guess is that it's reading the newline from your previous input.)