# why does while loop in C terminates abrubptly

Tags: c, loops, input

Just testing some code; the following is supposed to run until I enter 'n'. But it stops after one round. Can anyone explain it, and help me implement what I want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  char another = 'y';
  int num;

  while ( another == 'y' )
    {
        printf ("Enter an number ");
        scanf ("%d", &num);
        printf ("square of %d is %d", num, num * num);         
        printf ("\nWant to enter another number y/n\n");
        scanf ("%c", &another);

    }

}
```

Thanks.

I really appreciate every one's comments. I did search online for GDB, and used it later. I have to say it made identifying the issue so much easier. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c).

Comment: Did it occur to you to use your debugger to check what had been read by the scanf, or even just to printf out its value, before posting on SO?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
scanf (" %c", &another);
       ^^^^^
```

Also it is better to write

```
printf ("square of %d is %lld", num, ( long long int )num * num);
                         ^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer without making me feel like I don't know anything!

Answer (score 4):

Add a space before `%c`

```
scanf (" %c", &another);
```

To eat the left out newline in the buffer after the previous `scanf()`.

---

1) Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

2) Do check the return value of `scanf()` (and other functions), to make sure that the values were read without any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @user3326293, you're welcome. :)