# i++ not working inside a while loop

Tags: c, counter

I'm helping a friend with her programming class, and we've come across something funny. We have the code:

```
void ingresardatos(struct alumno *lista){
int i=0;
char continuar='s';
while(continuar=='s' && i<20){
    printf("Valor de i al iniciar: %d  \n", i);
    printf("Introduzca el nombre del alumno:\n");
    scanf("%s",&(lista[i].nombre));
    printf("Introduzca la matricula:\n");
    scanf("%s",&lista[i].matricula);
    printf("Introduzca la primera calificacion:\n");
    scanf("%f",&lista[i].calf1);
    printf("Introduzca la segunda calificacion:\n");
    scanf("%f",&lista[i].calf2);
    printf("Introduzca la tercera caificacion:\n");
    scanf("%f",&lista[i].calf3);

    lista[i].prom=(lista[i].calf1+lista[i].calf2+lista[i].calf3)/3;

    if(lista[i].prom<=5.9){
       strcpy(lista[i].nota,"NA");
    }
    else if(lista[i].prom>=6 && lista[i].prom<=7.3){
       strcpy(lista[i].nota,"S");
    }
    else if(lista[i].prom>=7.4 && lista[i].prom<=8.6){
      strcpy(lista[i].nota,"B");
    }
    else if(lista[i].prom>=8.7 && lista[i].prom<=10){
       strcpy(lista[i].nota,"MB");
    }
    printf("Valor de i antes: %d \n", i);
    i++;
    printf("Valor de i después: %d \n", i);
    printf("¿Desea continuar? (S/N)");
    scanf("%s",&continuar);
}
}
```

It's supposed to be a grade list for a class of 20; you introduce the student's data until you press "n", and it saves them on a list. Now, I figured out the pointer part (I just really know Java, so it's kinda weird working on C), but what I can't figure out is how to make the `i++` part work. If you run it like it is, it'll start with `i=0` on the first pass, then go through all the code, and finally do `i++` before asking if you want to continue (it prints it on the screen). But then, when you press "s" to indicate you want to continue, it'll start with `i=0` again, and for the life of me I can't figure out why. I tried `i++`, `++i`, `i=i+1`, and so on, but nothing seems to work. I even tried making `i` a pointer, but Windows didn't like it and crashed my program every time I ran it.

If someone could explain just why it isn't working, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&continuar);` - `continuar` is a single `char` type. It will break the system since the string input will be at least 2 characters at that address.

Comment: It's not really valid to explain what happened after *undefined behaviour* but suppositions can be satisfying. It *might be* that because `i` is just above `continuar` on the stack, when you enter data for a **string** the `'s'` goes to `char continuar` and the string terminator `'\0'` goes to the least significant byte of the [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) variable `i`. Since you incremented `i` *before* taking the input, that *might have* overwritten the least sig byte of `i` with `0`, clamping its value to `0` and causing the behaviour you saw. ***IF***.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s",&continuar);
```

This should be:

```
scanf("%c",&continuar);
```

As you read into a single character and not a string of character.

With `scanf("%s"`, it will not only write into `continuar` but the memory around it (how much depends on the number of characters read) and so your `i` variable must be next to it and is overwritten back to `0`.

Edit:

As per @WeatherVane's comment, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543113/835629) should actually be:

```
scanf(" %c",&continuar);
```

Since you last read a floating point number, the newline (from you pressing enter) is still not read and would be put into the character.

Comment: No, it should be `scanf(" %c",&continuar);` with the space. Otherwise it will read the `newline` left in the input buffer after `scanf("%f",&lista[i].calf3);`