# Issue with for loop and scanf in c language

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I'm trying to make a simple program to calculate the average GPA but during the output the statements don't stop when they are supposed to. I don't think there's any problem with the buffers in the printf statements as I'm using a new line in every sentence. This in output for example:

```
Enter a GPA: 
9
Do you want to calculate the average GPA until now?
Press 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: 
Enter a GPA: 
y
Do you want to calculate the average GPA until now?
Press 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: 
The average GPA is 9.0
```

As you can see the loop continues and it prints out the question again.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    /*************************Variable declarations************************/

    float fGPA;
    float fUserInput = 0;
    float fArray[30];
    int x;
    char cYesNo = '\0';

    /*************************Initialize array********************************/

    for(x = 0; x < 30; x++){

        fGPA = 0;
        printf("Enter a GPA: \n");
        scanf("%f", &fUserInput);
        fArray[x] = fUserInput;
        fGPA += fUserInput;
        printf("Do you want to calculate the average GPA until now?\n");
        printf("Press 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: \n");
        scanf("%c", &cYesNo);

        if(cYesNo == 'y' || cYesNo == 'Y')
            break;
        else if(cYesNo == 'n' || cYesNo == 'N')   
            continue;
    }//End for loop

    printf("The average GPA is %.1f\n", fGPA / x);

}//End main
```

Comment: You should print the value of `cYesNo` just to be sure of what is in.

Comment: `'\n'` != `'y'`, `'y'` is not a valid floating-point number to convert.

Comment: You do realize that the whole block `else if(cYesNo == 'n' || cYesNo == 'N')   continue;` does nothing, yeah?

Comment: @Lundin: If you're going to critique the program in general, why not mention the possible floating-point division by zero, and the zeroing of the accumulator in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**
this happens due to the white space i.e, `'\n'` character entered at the end of inputting `fUserInput`

```
    scanf("%f", &fUserInput);
```

this `'\n'` is consumed by the `%c` in `scanf("%c", &cYesNo);`

---

**Solution:**

avoid it by giving a space before `%c` in scanning `cYesNo` to consume any white spaces

```
    scanf(" %c", &cYesNo);
```

> **Why to give a space?**
>
> By giving a space,the compiler consumes the `'\n'` character or any other white space (`'\0'`,`'\t'` or `' '` ) from the
>   previous `scanf()`

---

**Suggestion**

next time if you encounter such problem... try printing the `ascii values` scanned by the character this way:

```
printf("%d",(int)cYesNo); //casting char->int
```

and check your output against ascii table : [here](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html)

for example :

- output would be `32` if it's a `' ' //space`
- output would be `10` if it's a `'\n' //new-line`
- output would be `9` if it's a `'\t'` //horizontal-tab

this way you'd know what's being scanned into the character and if it's a `whitespace` avoid it by the above method :)

Comment: Thanks @Cherubim Anand

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace

```
scanf("%c", &cYesNo);
```

by

```
scanf(" %c", &cYesNo);
```

for reasons detailled here: [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)