# When I Enter Second Value in Program its Take me to Third Value and not execute properly

Tags: c++

When I Enter Second Value in Program its Take me to Third Value and not execute properly

when I enter the gender it should ask me to enter degree but  take me to enter the third value and program not working properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char gender; 
    char degree;
    int age;
    printf("Enter Gender (F/M) ");
    scanf("%c",&gender);
    printf("Enter Degree ");
    scanf("%c",&degree);
    printf("Enter Age ");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    if(gender == 'M')
    {
        if(degree == 'P')
        {
            if(age >= 35 && age <= 50)
            printf("Good Work");
            else
            printf("Better Luck Next Time");
        }
        else
        {
            if(degree == 'G')
            {
                if(age >= 22 && age <= 40)
                printf("Good Work");
                else
                printf("Next Time");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(degree == 'P')
        printf("Good Work");
        else
        printf("Next Time");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Use `cin` function instead of `scanf`. It will solve your problem.

Comment: It's Worked Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char gender; 
    char degree;
    int age;
    cout<< "Enter Gender (F/M) ";
    cin>>gender;
    cout<<"Enter Degree ";
    cin>>degree;
    cout<<"Enter Age ";
    cin>>age;
    if(gender == 'M')
    {
        if(degree == 'P')
        {
            if(age >= 35 && age <= 50)
            printf("Good Work");
            else
            printf("Better Luck Next Time one");
        }
        else
        {
            if(degree == 'G')
            {
                if(age >= 22 && age <= 40)
                printf("Good Work");
                else
                printf("Next Time two");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(degree == 'P')
        printf("Good Work");
        else
        printf("Next Time three");
    }
    getch();
}
```