# Why my c program only produce zero answer while using for loop?

Tags: c

I tried to use for loop calculate the number of books keyed in and sum up their total price, but at the end i only get zero price in C program. What is my problem ? How to solve it?

```
 #include<stdio.h>     

 int main(void)          
 {      
        int booknum;                  
        float bookfee,bookgst,nogst,totfee,newfee,newfee_nogst;           
        bookgst=0.0;                
        nogst=0.0;                
        int cnt;                    
        char code;                           
        printf("Key in total books purchased >> ");                 
        scanf("%d",&booknum);

        for(cnt=1;cnt<=booknum;cnt++)
        {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("Key in price of the book >> ");
            scanf("%f",&bookfee);
            printf("Key in type( S=standard gst,Z=zero gst) \n>> ");
            scanf("%c",&code);
            getchar();
            if(code=='S')
            {
                newfee=bookfee+0.6;
            }
            else if(code=='Z')
            {
                newfee_nogst=bookfee;
            }
            bookgst=bookgst+newfee;
            nogst=nogst+newfee_nogst;
            printf("\n");

        }
        totfee=bookgst+nogst;
        printf("Book purchased with GST    : RM %.2f\n",bookgst);
        printf("Book purchased without GST : RM %.2f\n",nogst);
        printf("Total payment              : RM %.2f\n",totfee);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to move the updates to `bookgst` and `nogst` up into the `if/else` bodies, other wise a code-Z followed by 3 code-Ss will result in `newfee_nogst` being added to `nogst` 4 times.  Inside your for loop, you probably want an `else { printf("not a valid code: %s (0x%02x)\n", code,
 (int)code);}` I think your `scanf`s are leaving the <enter> keystroke in the input buffer as well---adding the 'else' case should help diagnose this.

Comment: Thanks for the informations guys.

Comment: What if an invalid `code` is entered?

Comment: @JUZ Aviewer Use a space in the format specifier  scanf(" %c",&code); Otherwise new line character is read.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code, but you're almost there!

First `code` reading needs to eat the previous `\n` ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)), otherwise the code is neither `Z` not `S` (it's a newline), and that's why the fees are never added.
(Search also for "fgets vs scanf" to see how to use the safer `fgets`).

```
scanf(" %c",&code);
```

then these lines

```
bookgst=bookgst+newfee;
nogst=nogst+newfee_nogst;
```

add the newfee / newfee_nogst ; these variables are set to `0` before the loop, but at the next occurence, they're still set to the value of the previous occurrence, thus either set them to `0` at the beginning of the loop, or, add the value directly in the `if` (see below). And since we're here, print an error if the code is wrong (and maybe subtract one to `cnt` to do one more loop with a correct code, in this case).

Also, the  GST calculation is probably wrong, 6% of x is `0.06 * x`, and if you want GST added to the value that's `x * 1.06`

```
if(code=='S')
{
    bookgst = bookgst + bookfee*1.06; // or bookgst += bookfee*1.06
}
else if(code=='Z')
{
    nogst = nogst + bookfee; // or nogst += bookfee
}
else {
    printf("Code not understood\n");
}
```