# Why I am getting this strange output?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Numbera are %d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the Program

```
Input 12 a
Outptut 12 0
```

Should not I get output 12 97(ASCII value of a)

Comment: `a` is not a number

Comment: If you want to get a character, don't use `%d`.

Comment: [How to do scanf for single char in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c) ? (misleading title, but works)

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not get "12 97".  That's not the way `%d` works.  `%d` expects to see digits, and digits only.

If you modify your program like this:

```
int r1, r2;
printf("enter number\n");
r1 = scanf("%d",&a);
printf("enter number\n");
r2 = scanf("%d",&b);
printf("scanfs returned %d %d\n", r1, r2);
```

and type "12 a" again, you will see

```
scanfs returned 1 0
```

indicating that the second `scanf` call did not successfully read or convert anything.  (When you use `scanf`, it's always a good idea to check the return value to make sure all your conversions worked.)

If you want to read a character as a character, you can use `%c`:

```
char b;
r2 = scanf(" %c",&b);
```

Beware, though, that `%c` is a little different from most of the other `scanf` format specifiers.  You may need an explicit leading space, as I have shown here.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c) for more information.  (Thanks to @user202729 for the link.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter a character when scanning for a number and have it automatically translated. You would need to read it into a char and convert to int.