# how to make switch case with characters work?

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

I'm currently working on an assignment for my class. In C, I have to make a program that works with the roster of a soccer team, where you can update, replace, compare players etc. However, right now I cannot make any of the options in my menu work. This will probably be better understood with my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, jersey, rating, newJersey, newRating, playerJerseyNumber[5], playerRating[5];
    char choice;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter player %d's jersey number: \n", (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &playerJerseyNumber[i]);
        printf("Enter player %d's rating: \n\n", (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &playerRating[i]);
    }

    printf("ROSTER\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Player %d -- Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d\n", (i + 1), playerJerseyNumber[i], playerRating[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nMENU \nu - Update player rating \na - Output players above a rating \nr - Replace player \no - Output roster \nq - Quit\n\n");
    printf("Choose an option: \n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
    case 'u':
    {
        printf("Enter a jersey number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &jersey);
        printf("Enter a new rating for player: \n");
        scanf("%d", &newRating);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (jersey == playerJerseyNumber[i])
            {
                playerRating[i] = newRating;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case 'a':
    {
        printf("Enter a rating: \n");
        scanf("%d", &rating);
        printf("\n ABOVE %d\n", rating);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (playerRating[i] > rating)
            {
                printf("Player %d -- Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d\n", (i + 1), playerJerseyNumber[i], playerRating[i]);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case 'r':
    {
        printf("Enter a jersey number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &jersey);
        printf("Enter a new jersey number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &newJersey);
        printf("Enter a rating for the new player: \n");
        scanf("%d", &newRating);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (jersey == playerJerseyNumber[i])
            {
                playerJerseyNumber[i] = newJersey;
                playerRating[i] = newRating;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case 'o':
    {
        printf("ROSTER\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("Player %d -- Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d\n", (i + 1), playerJerseyNumber[i], playerRating[i]);
        }
        break;
    }

    default:
        printf("didnt work");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

now, the first part of my code works correctly. however, if i try to use any of the options in the menu, they do not work. it automatically goes to the default case and prints "didn't work".

right now, i am testing with

```
84 7
23 4
4 5
30 2
66 9
u
4
6
o
q
```

which does not work, even though it should update jersey #4 to a rating of 6.

Any ideas on why this isn't working? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer) because you use `scanf("%c", &choice);` as the next input after `scanf("%d", &playerRating[i]);`

Comment: You don't even need a debugger. Just printing the value of `choice` would lead you toward an answer.

Comment: "does not work" is a very poor description.

Comment: @Swordfish ...perhaps the `default: printf("didnt work");`

Comment: If you are learning C, do not use scanf.  Just avoid it.  Use getchar/getc/fgetc instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah i've heard that before, unfortunately i am required to use it for this class

Comment: @Swordfish you're right, sorry about that. I figured it out now but i will remember that for future posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use scanf(" %c", &choice)
```

The blank in the format string tells scanf to skip leading whitespace, and the first non-whitespace character will be read with the %c conversion specifier.

Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)

Comment: thank you for the simple and correct answer :) it works now