# printf in a while loop is printing twice instead of once

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, do-while

In this code it need to calculate the number of times the operators appear.
It doesn't calculate it and while running the code it prints "Please enter a note. to finish press Q:" twice and i don't know whats wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char note;
    int result1 = 0, result2 = 0, result3 = 0, result4 = 0;


    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a note. to finish press Q:\n");
        scanf("%c", &note);
        switch (note)
        {
        case'+':
            result1 = result1 + 1;
            break;
        case'-':
            result2 = result2 + 1;
            break;
        case'*':
            result3 = result3 + 1;
            break;
        case'/':
            result4 = result4 + 1;
            break;
        }

    } while (note != 'Q');

    printf("+ appears %d times\n", result1);
    printf("- appears %d times\n", result2);
    printf("* appears %d times\n", result3);
    printf("/ appears %d times\n", result4);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Next time you copy & paste the code from your IDE to your question exactly how it is.

Comment: Not identical question - but worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Comment: You are reading the character (ex. `+`) and then reading a newline (you pressed enter). You can not print the `Plese enter a note ..` if the last character is newline or if you receive a newline scanf again or similar.

Comment: Try using `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`

Comment: Tip: **always** add a `default` case to a `switch` statement. This helps you detect unexpected events.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, insert

```
  printf("note='%c'\n", note);
```

immediately after the scanf.
You'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf("%c", %c)`, you will be reading one character at a time. Which is fine, but..

`scanf` will not "re-scan" for input, until the buffer is clear.

So, if the user were to input something longer than 1 character, your loop will iterate for every character the string is long + 1 (`\n` counts as a character).

Example (note it loops 3 times +, +, `\n`):

```
Please enter a note. to finish press Q:
++
Please enter a note. to finish press Q:
Please enter a note. to finish press Q:
Please enter a note. to finish press Q:
```

That's the trick. You need to change your code to accommodate this (i.e. hide the please enter message until empty or read a char array `note[128]... scanf('%s', note)` vs. single character with a sub loop to iterate the over the input, etc. or some other way).