# C language: The Array did not return a correct value

Tags: c, arrays

I have an assignment in C language that requires to ask users to enter values to arrays. My idea is createing two different arrays which one contains integer values and the other holds character values. This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char continued;
    int i = 0;
    char instrType[10];
    int time[10];

    printf("\nL-lock a resource");
    printf("\nU-unlock a resource");
    printf("\nC-compute");
    printf("\nPlease Enter The Instruction Type");
    printf(" and Time Input:");
    scanf("%c", &instrType[0]);
    scanf("%d", &time[0]);
    printf("\nContinue? (Y/N) ");
    scanf("%s", &continued);
    i = i + 1;

    while (continued == 'Y' || continued == 'y')
    {
        printf("\nL-lock a resource");
        printf("\nU-unlock a resource");
        printf("\nC-compute");
        printf("\nPlease Enter The Instruction Type ");
        printf("Time Input:");
        scanf("%c", &instrType[i]);
        scanf("%d", &time[i]);
        printf("\nContinue? (Y/N) ");
        scanf("%s", &continued);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected value should be: L1 L2 C3 U1 
My Screenshot[image]

The loop just stopped when I tried to enter new values and the condition did not check the value even I entered 'Y' meaning 'yes to continue' please help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string with a character that is instead of using scanf("%s",&continued) try using "%c"

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is `scanf("%c", &char)` because `scanf()` after had read the input print a `\n` to pass at the next line, this cause that the next `scanf()` instead of reading your input, go to read `\n`, causing the failure in the reading of the input.
To avoid this problem put a space before `%c` ==> `scanf(" %c", &char)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char continued;
    int i = 0;
    char instrType[10];
    int time[10];

    do
    {
        printf("L-lock a resource\n");
        printf("U-unlock a resource\n");
        printf("C-compute\n");
        printf("Please Enter The Instruction Type and Time Input: ");
        scanf(" %c%d", &instrType[i], &time[i]);
        printf("Continue? (Y/N) ");
        scanf(" %c", &continued);
        i++;
    } while (continued == 'Y' || continued == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Other things:

Instead of `i = i + 1` you can use `i++`

Instead of using a `while()` is better using a `do{...}while()` for saving some line of code.

You can concatenate more inputs in a single line ==> `scanf(" %c%d", &instrType[i], &time[i])`