# My if statement is not working in a while loop. After one execution it quits the loop

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I have written following code where 2 numbers are generated randomly and added into third variable. It then asks the user for accurate answer. Currently right answer is always `'A'`. `a1` is the actual answer whereas `a2,a3,a4` are the randomly generated answers.

I have put condition to see if the answer given is in the range of `a,b,c,d` or `A,B,C,D` using ASCII values. If it does not fit then message given is `invalid answer`.

If the answer is `'A'` or `'a'` it gives message `"Answer is correct!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)"` else it shows `"Answer is incorrect!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)"`.

After any answer it asks whether the user wants to continue. However after `"Do you want to play again?"` it exits the compiler even the `scanf` function is there.

I want to keep it repeating till user answers anything else than `'y'` or `'Y'`. As the `char` data type was not working I have tried to uses integer variable 'condition' but still not getting desired answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n1, n2, a1, a2, a3, a4, condition = 1;
    char again = 0, answer;
    srand(time(0));

    while (condition == 1) {
        n1 = rand() % 10;
        n2 = rand() % 10;

        printf("\n\n%d + %d=\n\n", n1, n2);

        a1 = n1 + n2;
        a2 = rand() % a1;
        a3 = rand() % a1 + 10;
        a4 = rand() % a1 + 2;

        printf("Your options are:\n\nA) %d\nB) %d\nC) %d\nD) %d\n\n "
               "What is your answer:\n", a1, a2, a3, a4);

        scanf("%c", &answer);

        if (answer > 64 && answer < 69) {
            if (answer == 'a' || answer == 'A') {
                printf("Answer is correct!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)");
            } else {
                printf("Answer is incorrect!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)");
            }
        } else if (answer > 96 && answer < 101) {
            if (answer == 'a' || answer == 'A') {
                printf("Answer is correct!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)");
            } else {
                printf("Answer is incorrect!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Invalid answer!\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)");
        }

        scanf("%c", &again);

        if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') {
            condition = 1;
        } else {
            condition = 0;
        }
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&again);`-->        `scanf(" %c",&again);` and `scanf("%c",&answer);` --> `scanf(" %c",&answer);`

Comment: See this as the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/debugging-code-beginner/). Use a debugger to step through your code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: And some critique of your code: First of all don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like `64` or `101`. Then if `answer>64 && answer<69` is true you know that `answer == 'a'` *will* be false so you don't need to check for it. And all of that code checking letters could be changed to a single `switch` (and with simpler cases if you use e.g. [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I agree with your comment, the OP should use `if (isalpha((unsigned char)answer))` and `if (tolower((unsigned char)answer) == 'a')`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf("%c",&again);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&again);
```

see [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)

or read David's comment below.

Comment: You  should explain how the `"%c"` and `"%[...]"` conversion specifiers do not consume leading whitespace. (`'\n'` being whitespace). So every time the user presses [Enter] and generates a `'\n'` character in `stdin`, the next call to `scanf` using the `"%c"` conversion specifier happily accepts the `'\n'` as the users input to the next question. You should explain how by placing a literal `space` in front of the conversion specifier, e.g. `" %c"` you force the removal of all whitespace characters leaving the wanted character to be read on the next call to `scanf`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. While the link explains exactly that, I could probably have elaborated... Your explanation is lovely as well though so I'll just point to that. Thank you @DavidC.Rankin :)

Answer (score -2):

this is scanf's bug.
you need use getchar() after use scanf to avoid your 'Enter' input to this function.

`scanf("%c",&again);` ->`scanf("%c",&again); getchar()`

Comment: This isn't a "bug", it's well-documented behavior that has an equally well-documented solution (which doesn't involve `getchar`).