# If statement in C aren't running

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-if

I want to code a program that can calculate the area of a triangle based on the user's input, I am Brazilian so the print is in Portugues, however i think that it won't change anynthing.
So my problem is the first "if" runs perfect, but the second "if" only prints the first line (Voce tem o valor dos 3 lados? (s ou n): ) and the program stop running, i can't find where my mistake is if someone can help me it would be good, and if the portuguese is making it more difficult let me know and I translate it.
thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void triangulo(){

int angulo;
float a, b, c, s, area, base, altura, seno, rad;
char resposta1, resposta2;


printf("Voce tem os valores da base e da altura? (s ou n):  ");
scanf("%c", &resposta1);

if (resposta1 == 's'){

   printf("Digite a base do triangulo : ");
   scanf("%f", &base);


   printf("Digite a altura do triangulo : ");
   scanf("%f", &altura);

   area = (base * altura)/2;

   printf("A area do triangulo eh : %f", area);

}

else{

  if(resposta1 == 'n'){

        printf("Voce tem o valor dos 3 lados? (s ou n): ");
        scanf("%c", &resposta2);

        if(resposta2 == 's'){


        printf("Digite o valor do lado : ");
        scanf("%f", &a);

        printf("Digite o valor do lado : ");
        scanf("%f", &b);

        printf("Digite o valor do lado : ");
        scanf("%f", &c);

        s = (a + b + c)/2;

        area = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

        printf("A area do triangulo eh : %f", area);
   }


    else{   
       if(resposta2 == 'n'){

         printf("Digite o lado : ");
         scanf("%f", &a);

         printf("Digite o outro lado : ");
         scanf("%f", &b);

         printf("Digite o angulo entre esses dois lados : ");
         scanf("%d", &angulo);

         rad = 3.14159265358979323846/180;

         seno = sin(rad * angulo);

         area = (a * b * seno)/2;

         printf("A area do triangulo eh : %f", area);
 }


}
   }
      }




 return;
        }

int main (void){

triangulo();


return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please read this. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: I don't think that there's any problem with your `if-else` conditions. I guess there's this problem with the subsequent calls of `scanf`. You should check whether they are `scanning` right values or not, using this example: `int test = scanf("%d", &b);`.
And I would suggest you to use `switch-cases` in this context.

Comment: Thanks guys i changed the second scanf("%c") for %s, and i reorganized my code and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, change to `scanf(" %c", &resposta2);`, with a whitespace before the `%c`.

For a more complete response, check [How to do scanf for single char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `scanf` function, you are trying to get a character from the standard input but if you answer with `n` and press ENTER the standard input will buffer the `\n` character (when you pressed ENTER) thus skipping the second if when the answer is `'n'`. what you can do is add the `\n` character to your `scanf` function like this `scanf("%c\n", &resposta1);`

Another solution is to put a `getchar()` after the `scanf` function to read that extra `\n` character.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the second scanf("%c") for %s and it worked