# C- Linked List with *chars

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to build a simple linked list.

I have successfully built a linked list only with **int** variables but when I add ***char** variables the output is wrong.

The **int** values seem to be correct but the ***char** type are wrong.

The ***char** type seem to always be the last one inserted.

Sample Input

```
Number: 5
Character: a

Number: 4
Character: b
```

Sample Output

```
5
b

**************

4
b
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BOOKS
{
    int value;
    char *char_value;
    struct BOOKS *next;
} BOOKS;

BOOKS *insert_value(BOOKS *node, int n, char *char_value);

BOOKS *read_list(BOOKS *head);

int main()
{
    int aux = 0;
    int menu = 0;
    int option;
    BOOKS *head = NULL;
    BOOKS *tail = NULL;

    while (menu != -2)
    {

        int choices;
        printf("1. Insert Book\n");
        printf("2. Print Books\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d", &choices);
        switch (choices)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            int n;
            char char_value[2000] = "";
            printf("Number:");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("Character: ");
            scanf("%s", &char_value);

            if (aux == 0)
            {
                /*FIRST INTERACTION*/
                head = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                tail = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                head = tail = insert_value(tail, n, char_value);
                aux = 1;
            }
            else
            {

                tail->next = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                /*FORMING TAIL->NEXT*/
                tail->next = insert_value(tail->next, n, char_value);
                /*ASSIGNING TAIL->NEXT AS THE NEW TAIL */
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        { /*READ THE LIST*/
            read_list(head);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {

            menu = -2;
            break;
        }

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

BOOKS *insert_value(BOOKS *node, int n, char *char_value)
{
    node->value = n;
    node->char_value = char_value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

BOOKS *read_list(BOOKS *head)
{
    BOOKS *a = head;
    while (a != NULL)
    {

        printf("%d\n", a->value);
        printf("%s\n", a->char_value);
        printf("\n********************\n");
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `node->char_value = char_value;` ... but you don't actually `malloc` and copy.the string. You make `node->char_value` point the `char_value` outside, which is the same `char_value` you use for all inserts.

Comment: Adding to Ted's comment, in `insert_value`, change `node->char_value = char_value;` into `node->char_value = strdup(char_value);`

Comment: `node->char_value = char_value` does not copy the string, it only copies the pointer. If you want every node to have its own copy of the string, then you must somehow allocate sufficient space for the string in every node. One way to do this is to use the function `malloc`. You could also make every node contain a fixed number of bytes, but that would probably be wasting a significant amount of memory.

Comment: Adding to @CraigEstey's comment :-) Don't forget to `free` what you allocate.

Comment: @CraigEstey strdup is not standard C, I wouldn't recommend using it

Comment: @ShellCode But it _will_ become standard in C23 :-)

Comment: @ShellCode: I agree, but it probably will be in C23, according to [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup).

Comment: Nice I didn't know that

Comment: Thank you everyone that was really helpful !!!!

Comment: @ShellCode Actually, `strdup` is a POSIX standard. IMO, the source authority for libc is POSIX and _not_ ISO.

Comment: @CraigEstey POSIX just adds to what is required in libc by the C standard, like ISO/IEC 9899:2018. So you can have a fully compliant C implementation without `strdup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `char_value` from `main` to your `insert_books` function, and then saving this pointer in your newly created `node`.  The address of `char_value` from `main` doesn't change, so you're saving the same address to each `node` you create.  Since all these pointers point to the same place, they will all read back whatever value was written there last.  If you want to make a copy of string in each `node`, you can use (non standard) [`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or `malloc` more memory and use [`strcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html).  But, it's an odd design choice you're using a character array to accept one character anyway.  I recommend changing `char_value` in both `main` and `struct BOOKS` to `char char_value;`, then you can simply use equals assignment as with `value` to save copies of the char.  Be sure to [`scanf` a `char` the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c).

A couple of other things:

As written, you can change `scanf("%s", &char_value);` to `scanf("%s", char_value);`.  `char_value` is a character array, which decays to a `char*` in this context, there's no need to specify the address of `char_value`.

```
head = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
tail = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
head = tail = insert_value(tail, n, char_value);
```

This is a memory leak. You're allocating separate memory for `head` and `tail`, but then setting both pointers equal to the memory allocated for `tail` (the return value of `insert_value`).  The memory allocated for `head` is never `free`d nor used.

Answer (score 0):

This will help with the errors:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BOOKS
{
    int value;
    char char_value[2000];
    struct BOOKS *next;
} BOOKS;

BOOKS *insert_value(BOOKS *node, int n, char *char_value);

BOOKS *read_list(BOOKS *head);

int main()
{
    int aux = 0;
    int menu = 0;
    int option;
    BOOKS *head = NULL;
    BOOKS *tail = NULL;

    while (menu != -2)
    {

        int choices;
        printf("1. Insert Book\n");
        printf("2. Print Books\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d", &choices);
        switch (choices)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            int n;
            char char_value[2000];
            printf("Number:");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("Character: ");
            scanf("%s", char_value);

            if (aux == 0)
            {
                /*FIRST INTERACTION*/
                head = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                tail = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                head = tail = insert_value(tail, n, char_value);
                aux = 1;
            }
            else
            {

                tail->next = malloc(sizeof(BOOKS));
                /*FORMING TAIL->NEXT*/
                tail->next = insert_value(tail->next, n, char_value);
                /*ASSIGNING TAIL->NEXT AS THE NEW TAIL */
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        { /*READ THE LIST*/
            read_list(head);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {

            menu = -2;
            break;
        }

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

BOOKS *insert_value(BOOKS *node, int n, char *char_value)
{
    node->value = n;
    int size = sizeof(char_value)/sizeof(char);
    strncpy(node->char_value, char_value, size);
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

BOOKS *read_list(BOOKS *head)
{
    BOOKS *a = head;
    while (a != NULL)
    {

        printf("%d\n", a->value);
        printf("%s\n", a->char_value);
        printf("\n********************\n");
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```