# why this is not giving correct output while this is working on c++

Tags: c, char, scanf, whitespace, conversion-specifier

when I write this code in c it does not work but when I make few changes like replacing with cin and cout it works fine in c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
        int i=0,l,m;
        char str[10],c;
        printf("Enter string:");
        scanf("%s",str);
        printf("Enter character u want to search:");
        scanf("%s",c);
        l=strlen(str);
        while (str[i]){
            if (str[i]==c){
                m=1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                m=0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (m==1){
            printf("Present \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Not present \n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",c);` c is just a single char so you're getting UB

Comment: `scanf("%s",c)` -> `scanf(" %c",&c)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `scanf` for a single character as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543113/10076146).
Just replace `scanf("%s",c)` with `scanf(" %c", &c)`.

```
printf("Enter character u want to search:");
scanf(" %c", &c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` is declared as a single object of the type char

```
char str[10],c;
```

So to input data in the object using `scanf` you have to use the conversion specifier `%c` instead of the conversion specifier `%s` that is designated to enter strings and pass the object by reference through a pointer to it

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`. It allows to skip white spaces in the input stream.

Also the variable `m` should be initialized before the while loop like

```
int i=0,l,m = 0;
```

And the variable `l` should be removed because it is in fact not used. The call of `strlen` is redundant.

And you need to declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[10] = { 0 };

    printf( "Enter string: " );
    scanf( "%9s", str );

    char c = 0;

    printf( "Enter character you want to search:" );
    scanf( " %c", &c );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != c ) i++;

    if ( str[i] != '\0' )
    {
        printf( "The character %c is present in the string.\n", c );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The character %c is not present in the string.\n", c );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second scanf is trying to put a string into a single char. (scanf("%s",c); Either scan it as a char or int, or use an array to store the string and then extract the first char from it for your comparison tests.