# why can't I input a character with scanf

Tags: c, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

why is this not working? im new to C...
the scanf function works just fine with other data types, its just the char thats not giving me the option to input a character

```
char grade;
printf("Enter your grade: ");
scanf("%c", &grade);
printf("Your grade is %c", grade);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Comment: Do you call `scanf` before this snippet? Please edit your post to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ...because you'll be reading the previous newline. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: The code you show works fine if you put it into a `main` function. If it does not work for you, then it is due to some code you did not show. We cannot diagnose code you don't show. That is why you should add a MCVE as I mentioned above. You should read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about what you should care when posting at StackOverflow

Comment: "new to C" and "scanf function works just fine"; http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: hikkichuu, Try `printf("Your grade is %d <%c>\n", grade, grade);` and report the output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems before entering the character there are inputs of other objects in your original program.

In this case you need to write

```
scanf(" %c", &grade);
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`. It allows to skip white space characters.

Comment: ahhh I see it worked thank you! I thought it didn't matter if I had already input other objects,,,