# How to prompt inputs one by one in C?

Tags: c

I'm quite new to C programming and I have an issue with how the code prompts the input. I need the inputs under the input statement to come one by one.
Now the way the prompts are output is:

```
To add a new task enter the details below
Name of Task: Science
```

Then all the other inputs come as a group

```
Category of Task:
Information about task:
Due Date of Task:
Status of Task
 TD = To-Do
 IP = In Progress
 CT = Completed Task
Enter Status:
```

But I want to it ask for the name of the task first and once I input that information, it should ask the category
For example:

```
To add a new task enter the details below
Name of Task:
```

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char main_choice;
    printf("Welcome to your Task Management System\n");
    printf("What would you like to do today?\n A: Add New Task\n B: View Task \n C: Manage Tasks\n");
    printf("\nEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%c", &main_choice);
    
    if (main_choice == 'A'){
        char name;
        char category;
        char info;
        char date;
        char status;
        printf("\nTo Add a new task enter the details below\n");
        printf("Name of Task:");
        scanf(" %c", &name);
        printf("\nCategory of Task:");
        scanf(" %c", &category);
        printf("Information about task:");
        scanf(" %c", &info);
        printf("Due Date of Task:");
        scanf(" %c", &date);
        printf("Status of Task\nTD = To-Do\nIP = In Progress\nCT = Completed Task\n Enter Status:");
        scanf(" %c", &status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost always: use `fgets` to get a line of input, then parse that line. If you want to use `scanf`-like functionality you can use `sscanf`.

Comment: When I use ```sscanf``` it says Format string is not a string literal and for ```fgets``` do I just replace scanf with that?

Comment: Use a blank space in your `scanf` like `scanf(" %c", &name);`

Comment: Check this answer to read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using scanf in C you should put a whitespace before the %c like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &name);
```

It is required to put space before %c to skip the white space in buffer memory.
so that %c matches the character given instead of the space char.

Comment: I tried adding the space and now it works for the first input(Name of Task) but the rest come together.

Comment: did you add the whitespace for all of them and what do you mean by come together?

Comment: I did add a white space for all the scanf statements and now, the first input comes on its own but then the other prompts come all together.. Let me update my question

Comment: I think I see the problem so you want to haave names for tasks not just characters instead of having 
    char name;
you should have 
    char name[20/*20 as the legnth of your string */];
this is how strings are defined in C and then instead of using %c in scanf use %s
because %c is for chars and %s is for strings when you input a string in the command line and asking for a char in scanf it gives other characters of the string to the other scanfs

Comment: so you should have 
`char name[20]; char category[20]; ...etc ` and in the scanfs use %s instead of %c

Comment: Ohhh okayy...I've tried that and now it works but I have this message after each scanf line ```Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]'```

Comment: your scanf should be like this `scanf(" %s", &name);`

Comment: Yes thats how it is now

Comment: can you send me your code?

Comment: How can I do that? its too long for the comment

Comment: can you send a screenshot?

Comment: It doesnt allow me to post pictures in comments

Comment: Ive added it as my answer..The code works the way I want it to but it gives me the error message I mentioned earlier in the comment

Comment: Ok no problem let me send you what I would have done with one of the variables
`char name[20]; printf("Name of Task:"); scanf(" %s", &name);`
Did you do the same?

Comment: Oh ok Ive seen your response

Comment: Great please let me know

Comment: Oh you can remove the & before the variable

Comment: Oh perfect it works now. Can I know when I should add the &

Comment: & is an operator used to get the pointer to a variable so when you are using scanf you should give it a pointer to the variable in order to give the var a value here name is a pointer to name[20] so you don't need to have the & because writing just name is a way of giving a pointer to name[20]

Comment: Oh okayy so the value I input, will still be stored in that variable?

Comment: and you don't need to have '\n' before the printed outputs when you have a scanf because when you use scanf you press '\n' to submit the input so it takes that into consideration

Comment: No problem my friend :)

Comment: Alright ill add that correction. Thank you so much again