# why isn't the user input printing in c?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, user-input

```
int userinput;
char convertfrom;
float value;

printf("What do you want to convert? Enter number from 1 to 5: ");
scanf("%d", &userinput);

if (userinput == 1) {
printf("enter letter K or P: ");
scanf("%c\n", &convertfrom);
printf("letter = %c", convertfrom);
}
```

I input "P" for the second scanf that asks for a letter, but the code keeps failing to print "letter = P". instead it only prints "letter = ".
Why can't I print the user input?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Comment: Trailing line feed ? First scanf you enter "1\n", 1 is returned, then during next scanf "\n" is returned. Empty the buffer.