# for loop in between if statement is not working in C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row, col, i, j;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter the Value of Row or Column: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    col = row;
    int mat[row][col];

    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            printf("enter the value(%d,%d): ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Principle Diagonal is: [ ");
    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("] \nGeneral Diagonal is: [ ");
    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            if (i + j == row + 1)
            {
                printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("] \n Type 'u' or 'l' for Upper or Lower Triangular Matrix:");
    scanf("%c ", &ch);

    // upper or lower triangular matrix

    if (ch == 'u')
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && i > j)
                {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 'l')
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && i < j)
                {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // displaying the matrix
    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to get a input of a matrix from the user. I take character input from user.

He will type either 'u' or 'l'....

I will display a upper matrix if the input is 'u'
I will display a lower matrix if the input is 'l'

So in between if else statement I put for loops, but this for loop is not working.

If i drag out the for loop from if statement, it works properly.

So, what is the problem?
How can I solve this?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: <O/T> recommend writing some functions .. got a lot going on in `main`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your conditions are overly complicated: `if (i != j && i < j)` If `i < j` why do you check `i != j` as well? You already know that they can't be the same if one is less than the other. Also your loops are very iniefficient. If you only do something when `if (i == j)` is true, there is no need to have an inner loop. Just use `for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) { printf("%d ", mat[i][i]); }`. Only in case where `row` might be different from `col` you would need an extra check but you assign same value to both.

Comment: Also in this loop where you do `if (i != j && i > j)` (which should be `if (i > j)`) you could just change the condition of the inner loop to stop before `j` gets same or greater than `i`: `for (j = 1; j < i; j++)`. Don't run loops to do nothing. The runtime will increase a lot with larger values and unnecessarily nested loops.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]! There's too much code here and it also requires manual interaction, which is probably (you need to verify that!) not part of the actual problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Doing a cursory review of your code, one of the biggest things that stood out was the array index range being used.  You probably want to dig into some C programming tutorials as it pertains to arrays, but to initially point out, the initial array element is element "0", not "1".

So, in reviewing your various for loops, you would want to change your starting array element from "1" to "0" and change the range test.  Following is a quick bit of refactoring.

From

```
for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
```

In refactoring the various "for" loops in your code, following was some sample output data.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/UpperLower/bin/Release$ ./UpperLower 
Enter the Value of Row or Column: 3
enter the value(0, 0): 1
enter the value(0, 1): 2
enter the value(0, 2): 3
enter the value(1, 0): 4
enter the value(1, 1): 5
enter the value(1, 2): 6
enter the value(2, 0): 7
enter the value(2, 1): 8
enter the value(2, 2): 9
Principle Diagonal is: [ 1 5 9 ] 
General Diagonal is: [ 9 ] 
 Type 'u' or 'l' for Upper or Lower Triangular Matrix:l
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

This is probably closer to what you were expecting for input and output.

So the main things to take away are:

- Arrays, be they made of characters, integers, or other variable types start with element "0".
- Usually, working with "for" loops in evaluating an array of size "x", a conventional statement would be "for (int i = 0; i < x; x++){ . . . }

So try that out, and do dig into some good tutorial literature.

Comment: Also worth suggesting using `size_t` rather than `int` for indices of an array.

Comment: I would agree with that suggestion.

Comment: this is all good advice but doesn't answer the main OP's question, which is why do the for loops not run when inside the if condition due to the wrong `scanf` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue (well, one of your issues) is this line:

```
scanf("%c ", &ch);
```

Unlike `%d`, `%s`, `%f`, etc., `%c` won't skip over any leading whitespace (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc.), and what's happening here is that `scanf` is picking up the newline (`'\n'`) from your last entry and assigning it to `ch`.

Since `'\n'` isn't equal to either `'u'` or `'l'`, neither branch is taken.  You either need an `else` branch to handle unexpected input:

```
if ( ch == 'u' )
  // print upper half
else if ( ch == 'l' )
  // print lower half
else
  // print error message
```

or you need to make one of `'u'` or `'l'` a "default" case, such as

```
if ( ch == 'u' )
  // print upper half
else
  // print lower half
```

meaning, this will print the lower half for *any* input that isn't `'u'`.

Another problem with the `"%c "` format string is that trailing blank; `scanf` will not return until you enter a character, followed by whitespace, *followed by a non-whitespace character*.  Given the code

```
if ( scanf( "%c ", &ch ) == 1 ) 
  printf( "'%c'\n", ch );
```

you get this behavior:

```
$ ./scantest
g





v
'g'
```

I can enter a bunch of blanks or newlines following that `g`; until I enter the `v` (or some other non-whitespace character), `scanf` just keeps reading.

You can fix the `scanf` issue by putting a blank space *before* the `%c` specifier:

```
scanf( " %c", &ch );
```

this will tell `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace and read the next *non*-whitespace character into `ch`.  You should also check the return value of `scanf` to see if the read was successful.  `scanf` will return the number of items successfully converted and assigned, or `EOF` on error.  So you should structure your code as

```
if ( scanf( " %c", &ch ) == 1 ) // expecting 1 input
{
  if ( ch == 'u' )
    // print upper half
  else if ( ch == 'l' )
    // print lower half
  else
    // print error message
}
else
{
  // handle input error
}
```

Alternately, you can use `getchar` or `fgetc` to read the next character, but you have to handle skipping over leading whitespace yourself:

```
int ch; // needs to be int if you're going to use getchar

do
{
  ch = getchar();
} while ( isspace( ch ) );
```

This will keep reading the next character until you get a non-whitespace character or `EOF`.  If you go this route `ch` will need to be declared as an `int`, not a `char`, since `getchar` returns `int` and `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`.

You'll still want to handle that EOF:

```
if ( ch != EOF )
{
  if ( ch == 'u' )
    ...
  else if ( ch == 'l' )
    ...
  else
    ...
}
else
{
  // input error
}
```

So, that's one of your issues.  Another problem is that arrays in C are indexed starting from 0, so an N-element array is indexed from 0 to N-1.  You need to change your loops to

```
for ( i = 0; i < row; i++ )
{
  for ( j = 0; j < col; j++ )
  {
    // do something with arr[i][j]
  }
}
```

Some stylistic notes:

- The conditions `i != j && i > j` and `i != j && i < j` are redundant; those can be rewritten simply as `i > j` and `i < j`.
- You don't need a nested loop to print the diagonal; you can do that as

  ```
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    printf( "%d ", mat[i][i] );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code, first and foremost in C arrays start at index `0` not `1` so you need to change all your `for` loops from

```
for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
    {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
```

you also need to remove the `=` from `<=` to avoid going outside of the bounds of your array (with `row = 3` you have position `0,0 - 0,1 - 0,2 - 1,0 - 1,1 - 1,2 - 2,0 - 2,1 - 2,2` so you can't go until `3`)

changing this means that your check to get the general diagonal needs to become

```
if (i + j == row - 1)
```

instead of `row + 1` otherwise the wrong numbers will be read

the loops inside the `if (ch == 'u')` and `else` statements are never run because you have

```
scanf("%c ", &ch);
```

the correct syntax in this case would be

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

(note the space `before` the `&c` and not `after`, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c) question to understand why)

All in all this is the fixed version of your code (please note that it's [better to avoid scanf and use E.G. fgetc instead](https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). I only made your code work correctly with minimal refactoring, making it more robust is up to you)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row, col, i, j;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter the Value of Row or Column: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    col = row;
    int mat[row][col];

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("enter the value(%d,%d): ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Principle Diagonal is: [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("] \nGeneral Diagonal is: [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (i + j == row-1)
            {
                printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("] \n Type 'u' or 'l' for Upper or Lower Triangular Matrix:");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);

    // upper or lower triangular matrix

    if (ch == 'u')
    {
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && i > j)
                {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 'l')
    {
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && i < j)
                {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // displaying the matrix
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```